# SQL query - how to get value thats greater then 50 from a truncated value

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find this info anywhere.. Or at least not too sure if I am asking the correct question. But any help would be great please.

I have a sql query where the PRICE value can only be returned if its greater the lowest of 3 columns

But I'd like to have this query also only return values that are greater then 50 between the 3.

`SELECT id , name , least(coalesce(p1, p2, p3), coalesce(p2, p3, p1), coalesce(p3, p1, p2)) as price FROM invprod.invprod1`

How do I alter this query to reflect this?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Any example input and output you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you simply add `WHERE least(coalesce(p1, p2, p3), coalesce(p2, p3, p1), coalesce(p3, p1, p2)) > 50`?

Comment: Or turn your statement into an inner select and put your "where" clause on the outer select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no clean solution. You either add the LEAST statement to the where clause, or you make it a subquery and add the price to a where clause.

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    LEAST(
        COALESCE(p1, p2, p3),
        COALESCE(p2, p3, p1),
        COALESCE(p3, p1, p2)) AS price
FROM invprod.invprod1
WHERE LEAST(
        COALESCE(p1, p2, p3),
        COALESCE(p2, p3, p1),
        COALESCE(p3, p1, p2)) > 50
```

or

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    price
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        name,
        LEAST(
            COALESCE(p1, p2, p3),
            COALESCE(p2, p3, p1),
            COALESCE(p3, p1, p2)) AS price
    FROM invprod.invprod1
    ) tbl
WHERE price > 50
```

Comment: Little tidbit to help anyone who wants to google it: This particular use of a subquery is referred to as a derived table.